# How to do a Oracle SQL Left Outer Join on 3 tables with two left tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to figure out the best way to join 3 table with unique IDs where 2 of the tables need to be the 'Left' Tables compared to the 3rd table.  The 3rd table would provide all the nulls that I need for my analysis.

For example:

table 1 = table_r, table 2 = table_n, table 3 = table_t

```
unique_r    unique_n     unique_t    match
abc                      abc          yes
cde                      null         no
            efg          efg          yes
            jkl          null         no
```

This is an example result that I want to get, where table_r compared to table_t gives me the matches and the nulls and table_n compared to table_t gives me the matches and the null.  Then I would do a simple case statement to compare the result into one 'match' column and I would know what is missing.

My SQL of sorts looks like this which only give me the one left side.

```
select * from table_r left join table_t
on unique_r = unique_t
left join table_n
on unique_n = unique_t;
```

Thanks for any advice :)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I think you want to union table2 and table 3 together and then compare to table1 with the left join.

Comment: What do you expect in (say) the `unique_n` column for rows drawn from `unique_r`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your example query, you want the results to contain all the columns from all three tables.  Furthermore `table_r` and `table_n` seem to be unrelated, but I suppose you don't want a cross product of their rows.  This is a rather strange scenario, but you should be able to achieve it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  table_r
  FULL OUTER JOIN table_n
    ON 1 = 0
  LEFT JOIN table_t
    ON unique_r = unique_t OR unique_n = unique_t
```

Alternatively, this might perform better:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM table_r
      LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT *
        FROM table_n
        WHERE unique_n IS NULL
      )

    UNION ALL

    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM table_r
        WHERE unique_r IS NULL
      )
      RIGHT JOIN table_n
  )
  LEFT JOIN table_t
    ON unique_r = unique_t OR unique_n = unique_t
```

That supposes no `unique_r` or `unique_n` value in the base tables is `NULL`.  The two innermost subqueries thus select result sets that contain all the columns of their respective base tables, but *no rows*.  As a result, the `LEFT` and `RIGHT` outer joins in the middle subqueries should be very fast, yet they should produce results with the correct columns, in corresponding order, just as needed for a `UNION ALL` (which will also be very fast).  Obviously, this is an ugly, muddy mess.  Don't even consider it if the first alternative is fast enough.

Comment: Or if table_r and table_n are supposed to be related via their respective unique IDs, then you could express that in the join condition for the `FULL` join.

Comment: thanks for this ..I tried the full outer join table_n on 0 but I get invalid relational operator any ideas?

Comment: I don't have an Oracle instance handy on which I can test, but Oracle does support `FULL` joins.  The message probably relates to the `ON 0` join condition; I guess Oracle wants a relational expression instead of a constant.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: 1+ for avoiding  cross product of table_r and table_n

Comment: Added an alternative query you could try if the first version is too slow.

Comment: The first is perfect!  I was missing the 1=0, which I completely don't understand what that means in the query..but thanks so much!

Comment: 1=0 is a relational expression that is always false (because, of course, 1 is *not* equal to 0).  Normally one would use an expression involving values of various columns in the two tables being joined, but you want the *form* of a join without any bona fide joining, hence a join condition that is always false.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same fields in table_r and table_n, you can do a UNION with *, otherwise, specify the fields you want to select, e.g an unique_n IS NOT NULL as match

```
select * from table_r left join table_t
on unique_r = unique_t
Union
select * from table_n left join table_t
on unique_n = unique_t
```

Comment: `UNION ALL` should certainly be considered instead of `UNION` if you do it that way.

Comment: unforunately they do not have the same columns ;(

Answer (score 0):

start with a centralized union from ALL tables, then left-join on them back to each original table...

```
select
      r.unique_r,
      n.unique_n,
      t.unique_t
      case when (
           case when r.unique_r is null then 0 else 1 end
         + case when n.unique_n is null then 0 else 1 end
         + case when t.unique_t is null then 0 else 1 end >= 2 ) then 'yes' else 'no' end as Matched
   from 
      ( select unique_r as base1 from table_r
        union select unique_n from table_n
        union select unique_t from table_t ) allBase
         left join table_r r
            on allBase.base1 = r.unique_r
         left join table_n n
            on allBase.base1 = n.unique_n
         left join table_t t
            on allBase.base1 = t.unique_t
```

Comment: Cute, but the subquery and can be eliminated by joining table_r and table_n with a `FULL OUTER JOIN`.  That would be clearer, and the performance must be at least as good.  The full join condition then determines how to handle values that appear both in the unique_r and the unique_n columns.